# How to change below given code from VB to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have given a vb.net function which I have to convert it into C#. This function handles checkbox event changed.

```
Private Sub ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles
                              CBD.CheckedChanged,
                              Travelkm.TextChanged,
                              Priority.CheckedChanged,
                              OtherCost.TextChanged,
                              Dangerous.CheckedChanged,
                              Over5Kg.CheckedChanged,
                              Living.CheckedChanged,
                              Guarantee.CheckedChanged,
                              NoGuarantee.CheckedChanged,
                              Corporate.CheckedChanged,
                              UnusualShape.CheckedChanged,
                              Over40kg.CheckedChanged,
                              Fragile.CheckedChanged
                Me.CalculateQuote()                                   
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't have `Handles` equivalent. You have to wire it up in your constructor. The designer (WPF or WinForms) can do that for you as well through `InitializeComponent()` which is invoked from constructor.

With that many controls using a single event handler, it might be considerate to wire them up in a loop (in case they reside in a single container or there are no other CheckBoxes in the entire Form/Window). If there is no direct way of uniquely identifying these specific CheckBoxes, you use their `Tag` property to distinguish them from others.

So overall it would look something like this:

```
public YourClass()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  foreach(var C in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Tag == "yourTag"))
    c.ValueChanged += ValueChanged;
}

private void ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
  this.CalculateQuote();
}
```

Comment: As long as the value of each of those controls doesn't change, this is correct (and it's *unlikely* that those controls *would* change). However, there's a nuance in the way `Handles` works in that if the value changes, it rewires the event to the new instance using property accessors. If the designer were to use the `AddHandler` statement instead of declaring the controls with the `WithEvents` keyword, it would be functionally identical to the C# `+=` syntax shown here. Just FYI.

Comment: @madreflection: *value of each of those controls doesn't change*: You mean to say **name of those conrtrols**, yes? Why would a value change rewrite/re-attach event handler?

Comment: When you add a control in WinForms, for example, the designer declares it using `WithEvents`, which allows the handler to be added to the control's event using the `Handles` keyword. Controls like the OP's `Travelkm` is declared this way. VB generates a property for the control, not a field. The get accessor just returns `_Travelkm` (the backing variable) but the set accessor *removes* (`-=`) the handler from the event on the old value of `_Travelkm` and *adds* (`+=`) the handler to the new value being assigned.

Comment: So if `Travelkm` were reassigned, e.g. `Travelkm = New CheckBox : Me.Controls.Add(Travelkm)`, the new instance would have the same handler applied and the old one (not yet removed from the form, by the way) would *not* have the handler attached anymore. Now, *why* you would do that is beyond me, but that's how it would behave.

Comment: @madreflection: Ah, now I see what you're saying. Thanks for the input. My impression is that the old instance will eventually be `GC`ed since there's nothing wired to it now.

Comment: That's true, but the point is more than you wouldn't have to think about attaching the handler to the new instance because it's done for you. VB treats of the control name more like a "named thing" rather than an "instance of a thing", so it keeps the handler attached to whichever instance you have for that named thing rather just the instance created at initialization. This isn't limited to designers, either... anything declared `WithEvents` will behave this way. In C#, you'd have to attach the handler to the new instance yourself.

Comment: @madreflection: Appreciate that. Easy to miss those subtle things without someone pointing them out for you. Thank you.